# evalute an integral with beta function 3

Tags: calculus, improper-integrals, beta-function

I need to evaluate the integral

$$ I=\int_0^{\pi/4} \sin^4 \theta \cos^5 2\theta~d\theta$$

I am thinking of changing $2\theta$ to $u$ but then I have a problem with $\sin (u/2)$. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Please, explain clearly why you wrote "with beta function 3" in the title of the question. Is it a requirement about the method to be used to solve ? In this case specify precisely what is required.

Comment: I wrote it  ,because it is asked to use the Beta function in order to calculate the integral.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nu substitution is necessary. Use the fact that $\cos(2\theta)=1-2\sin ^{2}\theta$.  Expand the powers. Note that $\int_0^{\pi/4} \sin^{n}\theta\, d\theta$ can be valuated using integration by parts.

Comment: Thank you, so θ =arcsin(u) ?

Comment: Thank you a lot :)